# Where can I specify Volumes in AWS FARGATE ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have below data with me -

```
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    #ports:
    #  - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ./data/storage:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
```

I want to manually create task definition in FARGATE ECS and then add containers in it.[No Coding]
Where can I specify volumes specified above inside containers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your query specific to volumes, you would have to specify the volumes in a [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html) which is used to run a task in AWS Fargate. You can have a look at this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html). This also lists the limitation when it comes to storage in AWS Fargate. AWS Fargate does not support any way to have persistent storage except EFS which was launched recently.

If your use case allows EFS check out this blog which demonstrates [Amazon Elastic Container Service & AWS Fargate, now support Amazon Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-supports-efs/)